# PhoneGap application showing old iOS 6 keyboard and old picker

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova, ios7

I have recently started using html, javascript and css to build an app with PhoneGap. The first time I uploaded and ran it on my iPhone (running iOS 7) it showed the regular iOS 7 keyboard and picker. I then made some changes to the app, uploaded it and ran it but the keyboard and picker had reverted back to iOS 6 and before keyboards. Now what?

I am not using any external javascript frameworks right now and not using an IDE, just a simple code editor for explicitly writing the code.

Picker refers to the UIPickerView that shows in iOS web views on combo boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue for a while. I figured it was the javascript framework's fault. The real issue was the launch image. If the launch image doesn't fit the exact specifications it will launch the app in compatibility mode.

You can find the necessary specifications here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW3

As an aside, I used this app from the mac app store in order to get the launch images exactly right. Worked great for me. https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/asset-catalog-creator-free/id866571115?mt=12

Comment: Could you also link to apple's documentation on launch image sizes? My concern is that the app you link to might stop existing when this answer doesn't.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW3

Comment: This was great. Thank you!